# How can i add a host to an already existing object group in ASA

Tags: cisco-asa

How can i add a host to an already existing object group in ASA, without over-writing the already existing members ? Please suggest

### For Example:

Object  group TEST has 2 members, and i want to add one more host (192.168.10.10) to TEST, will the below add the one host or replace the existing 2 hosts with the new host

```
ASA (config)#object-group network TEST
ASA (config-network)#network-object host 192.168.10.10
ASA (config-network)# exit
```

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can post and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 6):

this type of object group is calles **Network Object Group** ,
so to create a network group that includes the IP addresses of three administrators for example , enter the following commands:

```
hostname (config)# object-group network admins  
hostname (config-protocol)# description Administrator Addresses  
hostname (config-protocol)# network-object host 10.1.1.4  
hostname (config-protocol)# network-object host 10.1.1.78  
hostname (config-protocol)# network-object host 10.1.1.34
```

there is no problem to add any entry to same exiting Object Group ,it won't remove any existing entry

[Cisco ASA 5500 Series Configuration Guide](http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/security/asa/asa82/configuration/guide/config/objectgroups.html#wp1071777)

by the way ***ASDM*** will be batter in such firewall configuration and will give you better visibility.

Comment: I'd actually stay away from ASDM. I found it always to be slow, clunky and not quite straight forward. Doing the config yourself is maybe a bit difficult at first, but at some point it makes just a lot of sense and it is really easy since you can prepare configs and paste them in

Comment: it is always **JAVA**  problem

Comment: Where there is Java, there is a problem :D

Comment: may you dig in cisco communities to find stable version . for me ***jre-7u45-windows-x64*** was the most stable one

Answer (score 4):

Your example is adding the host to the object-group. This will not remove any existing entries.
To remove hosts you need to do the following:

```
object-group network TEST
 no network-object <object-to-be-removed>
```

Answer (score 0):

Java 7 version 45 and 63 worked for me with asdm, lower your java security setting to medium and whitelist the ip/hostname of the ASA.

specify object group then add the network object-host followed by the IP desired.

These two links cover just about any issue you could have...good luck!

http://www.gomjabbar.com/2011/08/06/cisco-asa-device-management-%E2%80%93-debugging-asdm/#sthash.1JEplDUI.dpbs

http://www.winsysadminblog.com/2016/01/log-asdm-cisco-asa-get-unable-launch-device-manager-error/

Answer (score 0):

A better way to create object groups is to fully embrace object orientated programing:

#### Create objects

```
object network test
 host 1.1.1.1
object network test2
 host 2.2.2.2
```

#### Add the object to a object-group

```
object-group network testing
 network-object object test
```

#### Use the object-group in a access list

```
access-list test_acl extended permit ip object test2 object-group testing
```

The access list will look like this:

```
ciscoasa# sh access-list test_acl
access-list test_acl; 1 elements; name hash: 0x71b1e4a4
access-list test_acl line 1 extended permit ip object test2 object-group testing (hitcnt=0) 0x4398ab6a
  access-list testing line 1 extended permit ip host 2.2.2.2 host 1.1.1.1 (hitcnt=0) 0xf5676f24
```

If you ever need to change the ip of the object "test" you only have to change it in one place instead of digging through object groups

Adding additional objects is easy, just create another object and add it to the group using the same steps outlined above.

```
ciscoasa(config)# object network test4
ciscoasa(config-network-object)# host 3.3.3.3
ciscoasa(config-network-object)# object-group network testing
ciscoasa(config-network-object-group)# network-object object test4
ciscoasa(config-network-object-group)# end
ciscoasa# sh access-list test_acl
access-list test_acl; 2 elements; name hash: 0x71b1e4a4
access-list test_acl line 1 extended permit ip object test2 object-group testing (hitcnt=0) 0x4398ab6a
  access-list test_acl line 1 extended permit ip host 2.2.2.2 host 1.1.1.1 (hitcnt=0) 0xf5676f24
  access-list test_acl line 1 extended permit ip host 2.2.2.2 host 3.3.3.3 (hitcnt=0) 0x0be1c62a
```